# Design bug: scroll bar on user page

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

On my userpage it looks like this:

[image]

As you can see there is an extra scroll bar. I use Ubuntu 9.10 with Chrome 7.0.517.41.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not able to reproduce this. I'm using Chrome 7.0.517.41 OSX. Do you, or anyone else see this problem?

Comment: Actually, here at home with the same chrome version (but Ubuntu 10.10) I don't have the problem. At my work I cleared the caches but the problem exists still (Ubuntu 9.10)

Comment: Today the problem is gone. I don't know whether anything changed, but it is solved.